# fullwidth slider bootstrap

Tags: html, css

i m having here a little problem. im using the bootraps template carousel and i would like to have the slider which there is in full width and not minimized. How can i change this

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a  URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/" alt="Second slide" src="img/1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

here is the template [test site](http://limo.awesom-media.de) cause it is a lot of css

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Can you try and explain again? :)

Comment: if u visit the site, u see the carousel slider . what i whant is that the carousel slider should be fullwidth.so it should take the whole width of the viewport just like here [sample](http://templines.com/demo/html/autoimage-paralax/index.html)

Comment: It is fullwidth ... at least on my screen.

Comment: sorry i mean the height u see that the pic with the mercdes is pretty plugged

Answer (score 0):

i think you should you @media screen for this issue as Charles Ingalls said there is issue with height. And for your responsive design testing you can go throught

http://www.ddcantt.in/2014/05/responsite-design-testing.html